# Tile layout for highcharts legend items

Tags: highcharts, legend, tile

There is a way to configurate highcharts in order to display legend items as a tile? Or maybe just using the horizontal layout but aligning the items in columns?

At left is an example of how it looks now using the horizontal layout and at right is what I want (it's not a real screenshot but just something I made using paint)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [itemWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemWidth)

```
 legend: {
     itemWidth: 80
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntL7f/